# Using Apache beam Python SDK to run Flink Runner on Kubernetes but facing issue

Tags: python, kubernetes, bigdata, apache-flink, apache-beam

> Here is my Custom Dockerfile that include Flink and beam SDK

```
FROM apache/flink:1.16.2-scala_2.12-java11
ARG FLINK_VERSION=1.16.2
ARG KAFKA_VERSION=2.8.0

# Install python3.7 
RUN set -ex; \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev lzma liblzma-dev && \
  wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz && \
  tar -xvf Python-3.7.9.tgz && \
  cd Python-3.7.9 && \
  ./configure --without-tests --enable-shared && \
  make -j4 && \
  make install && \
  ldconfig /usr/local/lib && \
  cd .. && rm -f Python-3.7.9.tgz && rm -rf Python-3.7.9 && \
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python && \
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  python -m pip install --upgrade pip; \
  pip install apache-flink==${FLINK_VERSION}; \
  pip install kafka-python

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-beam[gcp]

# Copy files from official SDK image, including script/dependencies.
COPY --from=apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.48.0 /opt/apache/beam/ /opt/apache/beam/
```

> Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flink-jobmanager
  namespace: flink
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: rpc
    port: 6123
  - name: blob-server
    port: 6124
  - name: webui
    port: 8081
  selector:
    app: flink
    component: jobmanager
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: beam-worker-pool
  namespace: flink
spec:
  selector:
    app: flink
    component: taskmanager
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 50000
      targetPort: 50000
      name: pool
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flink-jobmanager
  namespace: flink
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flink
      component: jobmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flink
        component: jobmanager
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jobmanager
        image: custom-flink:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args: ["jobmanager"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6123
          name: rpc
        - containerPort: 6124
          name: blob-server
        - containerPort: 8081
          name: webui
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 6123
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
        volumeMounts:
        - name: flink-config-volume
          mountPath: /opt/flink/conf
        - name: flink-staging
          mountPath: /tmp/beam-artifact-staging # New volume mount
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 9999
      volumes:
      - name: flink-config-volume
        configMap:
          name: flink-config
          items:
          - key: flink-conf.yaml
            path: flink-conf.yaml
          - key: log4j-console.properties
            path: log4j-console.properties
      - name: flink-staging
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName:  staging-artifacts-claim # New volume
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flink-taskmanager
  namespace: flink
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flink
      component: taskmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flink
        component: taskmanager
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: taskmanager
        image: custom-flink:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args: ["taskmanager"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6122
          name: rpc
        - containerPort: 6125
          name: query-state
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 6122
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
        volumeMounts:
        - name: flink-config-volume
          mountPath: /opt/flink/conf/
        - name: flink-staging
          mountPath: /tmp/beam-artifact-staging # New volume mount
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 9999
      - name: beam-worker-pool
        image: apache/beam_python3.7_sdk
        args: ["--worker_pool"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50000
          name: pool
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 50000
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
        volumeMounts:
        - name: flink-staging
          mountPath: /tmp/beam-artifact-staging # New volume mount
      volumes:
      - name: flink-config-volume
        configMap:
          name: flink-config
          items:
          - key: flink-conf.yaml
            path: flink-conf.yaml
          - key: log4j-console.properties
            path: log4j-console.properties
      - name: flink-staging # New volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName:  staging-artifacts-claim
```

> Here is Beam job that I am trying run inside container image  apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.48.0

```
import json
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka, default_io_expansion_service

def run_beam_pipeline():
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    consumer_config = {
        'bootstrap.servers': 'cluster-0-kafka-bootstrap:9092',
        'group.id': 'beamgrouptest',
        'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
        'key.deserializer': 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer',
        'value.deserializer': 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer',
    }

    topic = 'data'

    flink_options = PipelineOptions([
        "--runner=FlinkRunner",
        "--flink_master=flink-jobmanager:8081",
        "--artifacts_dir=/tmp/beam-artifact-staging",
        "--environment_type=EXTERNAL",
        "--environment_config=beam-worker-pool:50000",
    ])

    with beam.Pipeline(options=flink_options) as pipeline:
        messages = (
            pipeline
            | "Read from Kafka" >> ReadFromKafka(
                consumer_config=consumer_config,
                topics=[topic],
                with_metadata=False,
                expansion_service=default_io_expansion_service(
                    append_args=[
                        '--defaultEnvironmentType=PROCESS',
                        "--defaultEnvironmentConfig={\"command\": \"/opt/apache/beam/boot\"}",
                    ]
                )
            )
            | "Print messages" >> beam.Map(print)
        )

    logging.info("Pipeline execution completed.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_beam_pipeline()


>ERROR that I getting on task manager
```

2023-08-04 11:38:20,857 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask          [] - No state backend has been configured, using default (HashMap) org.apache.flink.runtime.state.hashmap.HashMapStateBackend@722335b3
2023-08-04 11:38:20,864 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateBackendLoader            [] - State backend loader loads the state backend as HashMapStateBackend
2023-08-04 11:38:20,865 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask          [] - Checkpoint storage is set to 'jobmanager'
2023-08-04 11:38:20,872 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Source: Impulse -> [3]Read from Kafka/KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read.ReadFromKafkaViaSDF/{ParDo(GenerateKafkaSourceDescriptor), KafkaIO.ReadSourceDescriptors} (1/1)#0 (c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0_0) switched from DEPLOYING to INITIALIZING.
2023-08-04 11:38:21,761 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                         [] - The operator name [3]Read from Kafka/KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read.ReadFromKafkaViaSDF/{ParDo(GenerateKafkaSourceDescriptor), KafkaIO.ReadSourceDescriptors} exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
2023-08-04 11:38:26,227 INFO  org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.logging.GrpcLoggingService [] - Beam Fn Logging client connected.
2023-08-04 11:38:26,288 WARN  org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.logging.GrpcLoggingService [] - Logging client failed unexpectedly.
org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: client cancelled
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:530) ~[blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onCancel(ServerCalls.java:291) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:40) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onCancel(Contexts.java:96) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.closedInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:378) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.closed(ServerCallImpl.java:365) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1Closed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:923) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) [blob_p-dd40044e778dd6367f67c2c36a355148bf4a84e4-56a27c85764b7818c4cbb91ed427fa9e:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
2023-08-04 11:38:26,562 INFO  org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.logging.GrpcLoggingService [] - Beam Fn Logging client connected.
2023-08-04 11:38:30,556 INFO  org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory [] - Still waiting for startup of environment '/opt/apache/beam/boot' for worker id 1-1
2023-08-04 11:38:30,676 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Source: Impulse -> [3]Read from Kafka/KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read.ReadFromKafkaViaSDF/{ParDo(GenerateKafkaSourceDescriptor), KafkaIO.ReadSourceDescriptors} (1/1)#0 (c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0_0) switched from INITIALIZING to FAILED with failure cause: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
2023-08-04 11:38:30,683 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Freeing task resources for Source: Impulse -> [3]Read from Kafka/KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read.ReadFromKafkaViaSDF/{ParDo(GenerateKafkaSourceDescriptor), KafkaIO.ReadSourceDescriptors} (1/1)#0 (c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0_0).
2023-08-04 11:38:30,748 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state FAILED to JobManager for task Source: Impulse -> [3]Read from Kafka/KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read.ReadFromKafkaViaSDF/{ParDo(GenerateKafkaSourceDescriptor), KafkaIO.ReadSourceDescriptors} (1/1)#0 c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0_0.
2023-08-04 11:38:31,385 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Attempting to cancel task [3]Read from Kafka/{KafkaIO.Read, Remove Kafka Metadata} -> [1]Print messages (1/1)#0 (c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_03f93075562d7d50bb0b07080b2ebe35_0_0).
2023-08-04 11:38:31,386 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - [3]Read from Kafka/{KafkaIO.Read, Remove Kafka Metadata} -> [1]Print messages (1/1)#0 (c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_03f93075562d7d50bb0b07080b2ebe35_0_0) switched from INITIALIZING to CANCELING.
2023-08-04 11:38:31,387 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Triggering cancellation of task code [3]Read from Kafka/{KafkaIO.Read, Remove Kafka Metadata} -> [1]Print messages (1/1)#0 (c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_03f93075562d7d50bb0b07080b2ebe35_0_0).
2023-08-04 11:38:31,476 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - [3]Read from Kafka/{KafkaIO.Read, Remove Kafka Metadata} -> [1]Print messages (1/1)#0 (c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_03f93075562d7d50bb0b07080b2ebe35_0_0) switched from CANCELING to CANCELED.
2023-08-04 11:38:31,476 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Freeing task resources for [3]Read from Kafka/{KafkaIO.Read, Remove Kafka Metadata} -> [1]Print messages (1/1)#0 (c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_03f93075562d7d50bb0b07080b2ebe35_0_0).
2023-08-04 11:38:31,486 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Un-registering task and sending final execution state CANCELED to JobManager for task [3]Read from Kafka/{KafkaIO.Read, Remove Kafka Metadata} -> [1]Print messages (1/1)#0 c2ced87e2df3c8340f7f2a1591a7366c_03f93075562d7d50bb0b07080b2ebe35_0_0.
2023-08-04 11:38:31,823 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.slot.TaskSlotTableImpl [] - Free slot TaskSlot(index:0, state:ACTIVE, resource profile: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1, taskHeapMemory=192.000mb (201326587 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=256.000mb (268435460 bytes), networkMemory=64.000mb (67108865 bytes)}, allocationId: b3fd6c8cb7eb19827ddaa4abee90c774, jobId: 4b59f015afa0eb4c041c3a96ff7d299d).
2023-08-04 11:38:31,857 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.DefaultJobLeaderService [] - Remove job 4b59f015afa0eb4c041c3a96ff7d299d from job leader monitoring.
2023-08-04 11:38:31,860 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Close JobManager connection for job 4b59f015afa0eb4c041c3a96ff7d299d.
2023-08-04 11:38:52,429 INFO  org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.logging.GrpcLoggingService [] - Beam Fn Logging client connected.
2023-08-04 11:38:52,566 INFO  org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.FnApiControlClientPoolService [] - Beam Fn Control client connected with id 1-2
Aug 04, 2023 11:38:52 AM org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise notifyListener0
WARNING: An exception was thrown by org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport$1TerminationNotifier.operationComplete()
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/vendor/grpc/v1p54p0/com/google/common/collect/Lists
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.indexOf(ImmutableList.java:428)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.contains(ImmutableList.java:438)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport.getLogLevel(NettyServerTransport.java:195)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport.notifyTerminated(NettyServerTransport.java:203)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport.access$100(NettyServerTransport.java:51)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport$1TerminationNotifier.operationComplete(NettyServerTransport.java:141)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport$1TerminationNotifier.operationComplete(NettyServerTransport.java:134)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$CloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:1164)

```
> ERROR in BEAM-WORKER-POOL

Logging client failed: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Socket closed"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"Socket closed", grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-08-04T14:34:57.878849834+00:00"}"
>... resetting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py", line 363, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py", line 212, in main
    sdk_harness.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 262, in run
    for work_request in self._control_stub.Control(get_responses()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 475, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 881, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = ""
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"", grpc_status:2, created_time:"2023-08-04T14:34:57.947519126+00:00"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out how to use the flinkRunner.  So far I've only make it successful with portablRunner.  For long run, I think the FlinkRunner will be deprecated, so might worth to give it a try with portableRunner?

For your reference, here's the argument for my jobs.
This argument is for local docker-compose testing, that's why you see the value is localhost.

```
--runner=portableRunner
--job_endpoint=localhost:8099
--artifact_endpoint=localhost:8098
--environment_type=EXTERNAL
--environment_config=host.docker.internal:50000
```

For kubernetes, I actually run the python workerharness as PROCESS, and therefore both task manager and workerharness is on the same pod and same container. Here's the argument for my Beam job on kuberentes:

```
--runner=portableRunner
--environment_type=PROCESS
--environment_config='{"command":"/opt/apache/beam/boot"}'
```

Here's a simplified view of my settings:

- the dotted one is combined together in my kubernetes environment
- the solid box is the container I created in my local docker-compose.yaml

[image]

You can also find my local testing from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/lydian/f90ede7a61f568b6d0f43b763aca0327).